# How to copy grayscale image to RGB images red channel in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I have **two input images**, which are **greyscale** and I am creating one more **image**, which is **RGB** and should contain in the red channel one of the grey image and in the green the other.

```
Mat img, img2;
img =imread("above.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
img2 =imread("left.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

Mat * aboveLeft = new Mat(img.rows, img.cols, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

int from_to [] = {0,1};
cv::mixChannels(&img, 1, aboveLeft, 3, from_to, 1);
```

I've  tried to use the `mixChannels` command, to write `img` input into `aboveLeft`'s **first** channel, but I couldn't figure out the right syntax and get assertion errors.

Is this the right way to fill in a channel?

Comment: What should the blue channel contain?

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV: Taking a 3 channel RGB image, splitting channels and viewing an image with only R+G](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341910/opencv-taking-a-3-channel-rgb-image-splitting-channels-and-viewing-an-image-wi)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume `img` and `img2` has same *size* and *type*.

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("above.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
cv::Mat img2 = cv::imread("left.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

std::vector<cv::Mat> images(3);
Mat black = Mat::zeros(img.rows, img.cols, img.type());
images.at(0) = black; //for blue channel
images.at(1) = img;   //for green channel
images.at(2) = img2;  //for red channel

cv::Mat colorImage;
cv::merge(images, colorImage);
```

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that you have 3 grayscale matrices, you can use `cv::merge()`:

```
cv::Mat blue, green, red;
std::vector<cv::Mat> images(3);

// OpenCV works natively with BGR ordering
images.at(0) = blue;
images.at(1) = green;
images.at(2) = red;

cv::Mat color;
cv::merge(images, color);
```

As pointed out in the comments, you need to find a way to figure out what you want for the blue channel!

Answer (score 0):

/*Using OpenCV3

Take a Binary Image using zeros 
convert it to gray 
Then to color using*/

```
cvtColor(Image, channels, CV_GRAY2BGR);
Mat bgr[3];
```

/*Split the channels into BGR*/

```
split(channels, bgr);

bgr[0] = 0, bgr[1] = img2, bgr[2] = img;
merge(bgr, 3, channels);
```