# RasPi Cam C++ API - Color of image

Tags: c++, opencv, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I’ve just tried the RaspiCam C++ API from [here](https://github.com/cedricve/raspicam/tree/master/utils) and the colors of my photos are too blue:
[image]

Photo made by command `raspistill -o rcapture.jpg:`
[image]
It’s a bit too red, but much better than the first one

The first photo was made by [this](https://github.com/cedricve/raspicam/blob/master/utils/raspicam_cv_test.cpp) example

My aim is to get images with normal colors through C++ API

The final solution of this issue suggested by Juanpalma was in changing mixed up channels:

```
 cv::Mat image;
 cv::Mat channels[3];
 cv::Mat cbuffer[1];        
 Camera.grab();
 Camera.retrieve(image);        
 cv::split(image, channels);
 //here is the fix     
 cbuffer[0] = channels[0];
 channels[0] = channels[2];
 channels[2] = cbuffer[0];
 merge(channels, 3, image);
 //end
 my_message = serialize(image);
```

Comment: You need to adjust the white balance. There is an auto mode, check the docs.

Comment: @adrianN that's not a white balance problem, it looks like the red and blue channels are reversed.

Comment: @MarkRansom probably you're right, but how to fix it?

Comment: Without knowing more about the problem it's hard to say. How are you displaying the image?

Comment: @MarkRansom both JPG files in the question were generated by the code which I provided (c++ code - https://github.com/cedricve/raspicam/blob/master/utils/raspicam_cv_test.cpp - 1st photo and from command line - raspistill -o rcapture.jpg - 2nd photo)
If you need any additional information, please ask

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with `opencv` to help, I've added the tag and hopefully that will get some answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes red and blue channels are reversed you have to process the buffer:

```
void interchange_colors(unsigned char *data, int tam)
{
  unsigned char cR;
  for(int i=0; i <= tam; i+=3){
    cR = data[i];
    data[i]=data[i+2];
    data[i+2]=cR;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Juanpalma for your answer. I don't have a clue where to place the code you mentioned, but I found how to change channels here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341910/opencv-taking-a-3-channel-rgb-image-splitting-channels-and-viewing-an-image-wi. 
Anyway, it fixes the issue With picture from the camera, so I accept your answer.